# creating and Signing Public/Private Key pair Programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography, public-key-encryption

Please read the question first as the heading isn't very clear and I am not able to put my question in few words.

**My scenario is as such:**
I am creating a P2P application. A peer, during installation, generates Public and Private key pair and uploads the public key to my central server. When a peer A wants to communicate with peer B, it downloads the public key of B and normal encryption and data transfer takes place.

I need a little heads up for creating this public/private key pair programmatically. Again I need this public key of a peer to be signed by the central server's private key so as to know its authenticity.

Do I have to create a private CA sort of thing or any other way is possible ? If someone can help me understand this creating, signing, etc from programming perspective, that would be great. I am getting a lot of concept out there in google search but not much in coding. I am new to cryptography so any other idea to implement the same would be helpful.

Note: I cannot use any third party CA. And I am not using the certificates for authentication, but for encryption.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

classic PKI scenario ... you want a CA ...

all your peers need to know the public CA cert ahead of time ...

once a peer registers with the server, it should encrypt its own key so the server can be sure that the received key wasn't tampered with...

for data structure you should probably use X509

from the programmers point of view:

peer A wants to register with a new keypair ...

-> generate keypair
-> fill the identification details of a certificate, and attach the public key
(what you have now is usually called "certificate request")

-> encrypt the request symetrically (AES-CBC-256 with a random IV looks like a good choice)
-> encrypt the symertic key, and send that together with the encrypted request and the cleartext IV to the server (optionally, include a server provided nonce or addidional session data in the encrypted part)

on the server side:

decrypt, check the data, especially the identification information of the request
if that's ok, take the request (ID part + public key) and sign that with the CA key

report back to peer A and handover the signed certificate (since it does not include any secrets, that may be clear text or encrypted with the provided key for peer A)

once you need to make contact between the peers, you only need some contact information:

if peer X wants to contact peer A, all you have to hand out is the address how A can be contacted ... X then contacts A and asks for ID ("Hello? is this A? please give me your cert and here is my cert.") ... after certificates have been exchanged the signatures are verified ... if CA sigs are ok, both parties generate random numbers ("nonces"; number-once-used) and encrypt them with the public keys from the received and verified cert and hand them over to the other peer ... upon receiving the encrypted value is decrypted, and reencrypted with the other parties key, and send back ... upon receiving that decrypt the value with your own private key, and verify that it's the same number you sent ... authenticated connection is established and you can now proceed to handover symetric keys and start transfering encrypted data

if you think you can live without authenticating the other peer, you can directly start transfering encrypted data after you checked the CA sig on their cert ... but consider that in this case, an attacker can receive data that's not for him (he can't decrypt it, but he can pretend to be the other peer ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking something similar to this implementation but I had other implementations as well and was not able to figure out which one to go for. The other method I thought was to have the server create the key pair and certificate during registration and sign the certificate and send it back to the peer. But I guess I'll go with this implementation. And I am not creating a CA as in a real CA, however I'll have a self signed certificate and key pair for the central server. And use that to sign all the peer certificates.

Comment: Can you tell me any security implications of not using an established CA software and doing such task myself. The signing part seems very simple and I don't see any point of having a CA software for this.

Comment: well ... what is CA software? ... if you have a look at openssl, it includes a "tiny CA" ... a bunch of scripts around the basic operations of openssl ... what you are building is a CA ... matter of fact ... you CA will have a self signed cerificate ... ok ... look at other CAs ... all root CAs in your browser have self signed certs ... the only difference: those are delivered with the browser, or your operating system... yours will be delivered with your application ... this CA will be as real as any other ...

Comment: about doing that yourself: as mentioned openssl contains a bunch of scripts for this purpose ... of course they are designed to work with openssl, but they can show you what operations the "tiny CA" can do ... have a look at them ... implications are: you have to handle the dataformat yourself ... but that isn't black magic ...

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get many hits on the concept but not the programming is that it is hard to come up with a good protocol, and not *that* hard to actually program it. It is the right order to go with this too, this kind of protocol you cannot just program and document later.

It doesn't really matter much if you want to use the certificates/private key for signing or for encryption. The point is that the public key needs to be trusted. If you cannot trust the public key then you cannot guarantee that the encryption was performed for the right entity. This means that e.g. peer A was encrypting using a public key of M instead of B. This is almost always a problem, unless you are only interested in eavesdropping attacks.

As you seem to have a central server it seems logical to use a hierarchical trust model. For such a system PKI using X509 certificates and a central CA makes the most sense. You can use an OpenSSL based CA system or any other free CA solution such as EJBCA or some Windows server based solution.

When you have the CA running you are not there yet. You need a method for the peers to trust the root certificate of the CA. After that you need a method for the CA to trust the certificate requests send by the peers. Without more information it is hard to say what method would fit you best.

You should only worry about the programming when you've figured all this out (at the minimum).

Comment: Can you point me to any good tutorial on X509 and implementations ?